# Have more heading levels available in Pandoc?

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc, html-heading, heading

We're generating a pretty complex document using Pandoc, and we are running into Pandoc's limitation of heading levels (which is set to 6, I think it's based on HTML).

Given the fact that using `role="heading"` and `aria-level="X"` it's possible to create HTML heading levels even deeper than 6, I wanted to ask whether there's a way to make Pandoc generate deeper levels, too?

The thing is that we generate a Word Docx document, and Word does also support heading levels deeper than 6.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible with any Markdown parser. Markdown itself is limited to 6 levels based on the assumption that HTML is. As the rules [state](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header):

> Atx-style headers use 1-6 hash characters at the start of the line, corresponding to header levels 1-6.

In fact, when you use more that six hashes, the additional hashes are simply ignored. See [Babelmark](http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=%23%23%23%23%23%23%23+7+Hashes) for a comparison of many implementations.

In fact, the more explicit (and stricter) CommonMark spec [states](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.24/#atx-headings) that...

> More than six `#` characters is not a heading

What is interesting about that is that CommonMark is very new (newer than HTML5) while Markdown is very old (a late version of Markdown switched to the new hotness of the time: XHTML). The point is that the more lax spec is from a time when there was no way to represent more than 6 levels in HTML and the newer spec explicitly disallows more than 6 levels even though it might be possible in HTML.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, in HTML5 you can have as many heading levels as you want by using sections, articles, etc. How will Markdown cope?

Comment: I expect that Markdown will always be limited to 6 levels. If you need more then I would suggest looking for something other than Markdown. Although I'm not aware of anything else that supports more than 6 levels.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be fairly easy to write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) to extract the required attributes from the AST and modify it to a deeper heading, since the level is just an `Int` in the [pandoc `Header` definition](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L225).

So the input could be:

```
# my custom title {role=heading, aria-level=9}
```

or even just:

```
# my custom title {level=9}
```